# show all post with php inner join

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

So I have this kind of project to have post divided into several provinces. I can show the post but only 1 if there is 2 posts or more it will only show me 1 post. This is my code with PHP

```
<?php $p3=1;$posts=mysql_query("select * from provinces INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id_province=provinces.id_province");
                            while($ps3=mysql_fetch_array($posts)){
                                    $jdlpost=$ps3[nm_news];
                                    $despost=$ps3[desc];
                                    $jdlprovince=$ps3[nm_province];
                                                $link3=$_COOKIE[linkmenu].$ps3['id_news']."/"."news/".linktitle($ps3['nm_news']);
                                if($p3===1){
echo   "<div class=modal fade in' id='tc$ps3[id_news]> <div class=modal-dialog modal-lg> <div class='modal-content' style= 'margin-top: 100px;'>"
."<div class='modal-header'>"
                                    ."<h5 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLabel'>$jdlprovince</h5>
                                                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
                                                    <span aria-hidden='true'>×</span>
                                                    </button>"
                                    ."</div>"
."<div class='modal-body'>"
                                    ."<div class='row'>"
                                    ."<div class='col-md-12'>"
                                    ."<div class='box-list'>"
                                    ."<div class='detailgeo dg3 tampil$ps3[id_news] active view view-tenth'>"
                                    ."<div class='coverhover'><div class='imgs' style='background-image:url(".$_COOKIE[config]."dynamic/200/imgnews/".$ps3[pict].")'> </div>
                                                           <div class='mask'>
                                                               <a href='$link3' class='info' title='$jdlpost'><i class='fa fa-search'></i></a>
                                                           </div>
                                                       </div>"
                                    ."<div class='ise'><b><a href='$link3'>$jdlpost</a></b><i>".ucfirst(textlimit(rmSpecialChars(cleanHTML($despost)),180))."</i><div class='clear'></div><a href='$link3'class='remor' class='remor'>READ MORE <i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i></a></div>"
                                    ."</div>"
                                    ."</div>"
                                    ."</div>"
                                    ."</div>"
                                    ."</div>"
                                    ."</div>"
                                    ."</div>"
                                    ."</div>";
}else{
echo   "<div class=modal fade in' id='tc$ps3[id_news]> <div class=modal-dialog modal-lg> <div class='modal-content' style= 'margin-top: 100px;'>"
<div class='modal-content' style= 'margin-top: 100px;'>"
                                    ."<div class='modal-header'>"
                                    ."<h5 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLabel'>$jdlprovince</h5>
                                                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
                                                    <span aria-hidden='true'>×</span>
                                                    </button>"
                                    ."</div>"
                                    ."<div class='modal-body'>"
                                    ."<div class='row'>"
                                    ."<div class='col-md-12'>"
                                    ."<div class='box-list'>"
                                    ."<div class='detailgeo dg3 tampil$ps3[id_news] active view view-tenth'>"
                                    ."<div class='coverhover'><div class='imgs' style='background-image:url(".$_COOKIE[config]."dynamic/200/imgnews/".$ps3[pict].")'> </div>
                                                           <div class='mask'>
                                                               <a href='$link3' class='info' title='$jdlpost'><i class='fa fa-search'></i></a>
                                                           </div>
                                                       </div>"
                                    ."<div class='ise'><b><a href='$link3'>$jdlpost</a></b><i>".ucfirst(textlimit(rmSpecialChars(cleanHTML($despost)),180))."</i><div class='clear'></div><a href='$link3'class='remor' class='remor'>READ MORE <i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i></a></div>"
                                    ."</div>"
                                    ."</div>"
                                    ."</div>"
                                    ."</div>"
                                    ."</div>"
                                    ."</div>"
                                    ."</div>"
                                    ."</div>";
                            }?>
                            <?php
                        ?>
<script>
                                $(document).ready(function(){
                                    $(".maps<?php echo $ps3['id_news'];?>").click(function(){
                                        $(".dg3").removeClass("active");
                                        $(".tthree .posisi").removeClass("active");
                                        $(this).addClass("active");
                                        $(".tampil<?php echo $ps3['id_news'];?>").addClass("active");
                                    });
                                });
                            </script><?php
                            $p3++;
                        }
                        ?>
```

I don't have any idea how to retrieve more than 1 post in my code with same id_province. So I repeat again if there is 2 post with same id_province so it will retrieve like my 1st picture. Thanks

Thanks For helping guys.

Comment: what if($p3===1){ is doing?

Comment: Can you add whole code here?

Comment: wait yaa will add here

Comment: so there are many province and I add p3 to make it retrieve all province

Comment: Where is your else code .. because you are incrementing $p3++ so obviously it will not print other div because a condition is wrong

Comment: I think your logic is not correct

Comment: Hello I already add all my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190345/discussion-between-joy-and-ayam-geprek).

Comment: Please consider not using a deprecated and insecure API

Comment: what do u mean insecure api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I will suggest you to user `mysqli_query()` as MySQL function is deprecated already.

Based on your code you need to separate your query in 2 part

> 1) get data from the first table
>
> 2) get the data from the second table based on id

**Now based on the result you can show div as per your requirement.**

```
$posts=mysql_query("select * from provinces");


while($ps3=mysql_fetch_array($posts)){
        while($result=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select * from table2 where id ='.$ps3['id']))){
            // do code here
          }
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake when wrote it for question above. but already do that on my code. What I need is to retrieve all posts from same province

Comment: can you check after removing a $p3 condition condition

Comment: after removing p3++ it will remove my posts